# AWS Appflow | Trigger lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am pulling data from Salesforce using AWS Appflow and it is dumping data into S3. It is creating many files in S3. How can I run lambda only once per Appflow run. In my scenario, lambda is triggering n number of times, where n is the number of files created in S3 per run.

Note : 1. I can't create 1 file per run.
2. I am open for any other approach

Comment: what is the trigger that your using for the lambda function?

Comment: S3 put events .

Answer (score 0):

As you have made it clear that your using S3 event for the trigger.
That addresses the issue of why your lambda function is being triggered every time there is a PUT event on S3.

Unfortunately there is no such trigger that would help you in this use case.

If you still want to use Lambda you can have a cloud watch event as a trigger for lambda function like a corn job.
You can schedule it for any interval which you feel would be appropriate for the function.
Hope this was helpfull

Comment: I am sorry, I can't use cloud watch trigger as appflow creates logs in cloudtrail.

Comment: @PratikGarg cloudtrail dumps the logs in s3 and every PUT operation triggers a Lambda function. As i have mentioned in the answer it's tricky to handle with lambda trigger as there is no trigger for appflow. 
Hope SNS does the trick:
if you could figure out after each appflow you can have a notification which would trigger a lambda

Answer (score 0):

Appflow has the option of aggregating the files to a single file before loading it to S3. You can see that option in additional settings just before the scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mind my Lambda function get invoked multiple times, as long as it is idempotent.

Normally one AppFlow output file in the S3 bucket should only trigger your Lambda function once if the Lambda function can finish the execution within the timeout and return no error. Failing to do so may trigger a retry mechanism.

As @krr7931 suggested, you can try the aggregation option when setting up your AppFlow flow. AppFlow also supports filters, which can help reduce the amount of data you need to handle.

PS: here's my reflection on using AppFlow with Salesforce https://www.capturedlabs.com/amazon-app-flow-with-salesforce-in-action